# Where to see lay-outs of keyboards

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout, settings

I want to change the keyboard layout in xfce, but I do not know how my preferred layout is called. Is there a way to see (in xfce or on the internet) pictures of the layouts with their names?

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard mappings are managed by X (the window system), not by xfce (your window manager). (There's a second set of keyboard mappings for the Linux kernel and virtual console, but that's not relevant for your question).

X keyboards are desribed by the *model*, the *variant/layout*, and a set of *options*. See `man xkeyboard-config` for a list of those. The files to generate keyboard mappings can be found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`, and they contain everything that's available in case the man page is incomplete. See e.g. [An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058) for details on the format.

You can use either `setxkbmap` or the `xorg.conf` file to change the keyboard mapping to a specific keyboard. Both produce an `xkb_keymap` file internally, which is then compiled by `xkbcomp` to the actual keyboard mapping. The internal file can be made visible, for example,

```
setxkbmap -layout dvorak -variant intl -model pc105 -option compose:caps -print > map.def
```

produces the file `map.def`

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(dvorak)+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)+compose(caps)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

This file can be compiled

```
xkbcomp map.def
```

to `map.xkb`, which in turn be used by `xkbprint` to generate a Postscript file with picture of a specific keyboard

```
xkbprint map.xkm
```

and then viewed with `gv` etc., so you can see a picture after all these steps.

There's probably too many possible combinations to make an exhaustive set of pictures practicable.